# Reload youtubeplayer in activity?

Tags: android, listview, youtube-api

Please help me,

I want when user click item in listview -> Reload activity with video clicked (Like youtube app android)

Pleale help me the idea. Thanks

[You can view here](http://i973.photobucket.com/albums/ae220/huynn109/youtube.png)

**Update my source code:**

public class YoutubePlayerActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

```
private static final int RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST = 1;

YouTubePlayerFragment myYouTubePlayerFragment;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private String name;
private String countView;
private String youtubeId = "fhWaJi1Hsfo";
private String cate;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
private ClipAdapter mClipAdapter;
private List<ClipItemData> clipItemDatas = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube_player);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_recycler_view);

    // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
    // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    // use a linear layout manager
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    final LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        ClipItemData clipItemData = new ClipItemData("To0tJu75ugg",
                "Test",
                "123",
                "XE",
                "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + "To0tJu75ugg" + "/0.jpg");

        clipItemDatas.add(clipItemData);
    }

    // specify an adapter (see also next example)
    mClipAdapter = new ClipAdapter(this, clipItemDatas);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mClipAdapter);

    Bundle getBundle = null;
    getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    youtubeId = getBundle.getString("id");
    name = getBundle.getString("name");
    countView = getBundle.getString("count_view");
    cate = getBundle.getString("cate");
    myYouTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
    myYouTubePlayerFragment.initialize(AppConfig.YOUTUBE_ANDROID_KEY, this);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerItemClickListener(this, mRecyclerView, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
            youtubeId = "To0tJu75ugg";
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), youtubeId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(View view, int position) {
        }
    }));

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
        case android.R.id.home:
            super.onBackPressed();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    if (!wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.loadVideo(youtubeId);
    }

}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider,
                                    YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String errorMessage = String.format(
                "There was an error initializing the YouTubePlayer (%1$s)",
                errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == RECOVERY_DIALOG_REQUEST) {
        // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
        getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(AppConfig.YOUTUBE_ANDROID_KEY, this);
    }
}

protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
    return (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerfragment);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in different ways.

1. You can use a simple WebView to load those videos.
2. You can also use the official "YouTube Android Player API"

[YouTube Android Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)

Implementing Youtube's API is easy,

First create a `YouTubePlayerView`in your xml,

```
<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then show a video like this,

```
public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

 public static final String API_KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";
 public static final String VIDEO_ID = "YOUR_VIDEO_ID";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView)findViewById(R.id.youtubeplayerview);
        youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, this);
    }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider,
   YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
    "onInitializationFailure()", 
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 @Override
 public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player,
   boolean wasRestored) {
  if (!wasRestored) {
        player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
      }
 }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Prokash Sarkar,

i want to reload video when i tap to item in list view then reload in current activity

P/s: Sorry for inconvenience of first my question

Comment: You can add an onClickListener() for your ListView items. After clicking a ListView item get the url based on the position it was clicked then simply set a new url to the WebView/YouTubePlayerView of your activity. If you don't know how to use an custom Adapter for ListView and detect individual click on List items please have a look here, http://www.learn2crack.com/2013/10/android-custom-listview-images-text-example.html

Comment: Thanks, I solved.

I can not vote for you.

Comment: Please make the answer accepted if that helped you!

Comment: Sr, I can not reload video youtube when clicked item listview. I updated source code.

Comment: Inside your onItemTouchListener() use,  
myYouTubePlayerFragment.setVideoId(videoId); Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Class YouTubePlayerFragment not existing function setVideoId()

Comment: I use mYoutubePlayer.loadVideo(youtubeId); It's Ok. Thanks you.